# how save a physical image using fs extra with base64 text

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Please, could you help me? I would like to save an image, that is encoded in base64, using base64.

I have tried this :

```js
var image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
    image = image.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "").replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, "").replace(/^data:image\/gif;base64,/, "");
    
    var image2 = "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";
    
    fse.writeFile("image.png", image, 'base64', function(err) {
        if(!err)
            console.log('cool ok');
        else
            console.log('erreur' + err);
    });
```

The console log shows me that the image was successfully created, but it's impossible to open it. When i try to view the image, it shows me an error (the file is corrupt).

Could you help me?

Excuse my mistakes, I'm not very good at English.

Comment: I vote to close before I tried the code and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Buffer` to turn the ascii to binary then add `binary` to the `fs.writeFile`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var binImage = new Buffer(image, 'base64').toString('binary');
fs.writeFile("image.jpg", binImage, "binary", function(err) {
    if(!err)
        console.log('cool ok');
    else
        console.log('erreur' + err);
});
```

Comment: I tried what you said , but , i have the same error , when , i tried to view the pictures with my  i get that error  : Erreur d'interprétation du fichier d'image JPEG (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x75 0xab)

Comment: I'm not using `fs extra` just normal `fs` and the file contents I have starts with 0xFF 0xD8.  I'm not sure why you have a different header on your file.  Try deleting the file and running your script again.  My header has JFIF starting from byte 7.

Comment: Many thanks!! This really helped me out -- worked a charm :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your regular expressions to this:

```
 image = image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|png|gif|bmp|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, "");
```

I tested that on node.js and it worked and rendered that chick image you encoded.

Comment: Actually, the leading `/` is not being stripped. If you look closely, the variable `image` is being used in the `writeFile` function and not `image2`.

Comment: Ah sure sorry. Anyway, his replacement is pretty ineffective,.

Comment: I tried what you said , but , i have the same error , when , i tried to view the pictures with my i get that error : Erreur d'interprétation du fichier d'image JPEG (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x75 0xab)

Comment: @codevscodevs That must be problem with your image viewer or node.js. As I said, I tried that with node.js and it works on both windows and linux. Also nor English nor French typography puts space before comma, so **stop it**.

Comment: @TomášZato ok , i think that error is due to node.js because , this image can't be shown with my image viewer , i tried also with iceweaseal ( navigator on kali)  , but the image still does'nt shown